# Loguru - how to clear the logs

Tags: python, loguru

is there a way clear the log file before using it with the python log library 'loguru'?

Thanks!

```
from loguru import logger
#  clear the log before logging
logger.add('output.log', format="{time:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss} {level} {message}")
logger.debug('my message')
```

Comment: Calling os.remove("output.log") or logger.remove()  before logger.add() would help ? You also need to check if this exists or not if you use this function to avoid errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Loguru` API does not have the ability to remove/clean up log files. Instead of that, you could either use `open('output.log', 'w').close()` if you want to erase all contents of the log file. Or check the ability to use log rotation in `Loguru` if it's suitable for your use case (something like that `logger.add("file_{time}.log")`)

Comment: The `"w"` flag can be passed to `.add()` and it should work fine actually: `logger.add("file_{time}.log", mode="w")`.